# How to properly use react-native-app-link to launch an external app?

Tags: javascript, deep-linking, deeplink, android-deep-link

I'm trying to open an external app from my react-native app.

I tried to use [react-native-app-link](https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link) like this :

```
  openApp = () => {
  AppLink.maybeOpenURL('https://youtube.com', { appName: 'youtube', appStoreId:'', appStoreLocale:'', playStoreId:'' }).then(() => {
    console.log('url found');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('error app not installed');
  });
}
```

It works for youtube, BUT, for others applications like Google Photos, Agenda... It doesn't work...

Is there an universal solution to open an external app directly from mine without using the browser ?

Thank you

Comment: did you get solution to this? I am looking for same solution. also how do we get appStoreId and playStoreId for external applications ?

Comment: The only solution I have found was to create a bridge between android and react. 
To find out appStoreId you can use playstore searchbar and after clicking on app you can find in the url the appStoreId (ex: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en) ) 
Here you have com.facebook.katana but the better solution is to parse the app list installed on the device and get the app Id directly.
Unfortunately I have not access to the project right now to give you the code. Hope it helps.

Comment: any update on this @alexandrejeanjean